# Yeoman angularjs generator broken

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I just create an empty directory called "assets" with my php lavarel project folder and issue the following command -> yo angular, then in the terminal, I was asked include sass/compass, bootstrap etc and start installing this generator. somehow, I got lots of errors that i have no ideas what that cause. I need some help and here are the errors.

```
npm npm ERR!http Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'xxx/app/assets/node_modules/grunt/lib'
 GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd xxx/app/assets
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path xxx/app/assets/node_modules/grunt/lib
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno 53

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'xxx/app/assets/node_modules/grunt/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd xxx/app/assets
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path xxx/app/assets/node_modules/grunt/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     xxx/app/assets/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     xxx/assets/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Can you check the content of the npm-debug.log as stated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your user don't own your project folder. `chown` and `chmod` your folder so it work with the your user account.